# Imaged loaded with Glide comes with very low resolution

Tags: android, image-loading, android-glide

I am using Glide 3.6.0 to load images from the web. 
It works for 99% of the times, but sometimes it shows the images in very low resolution.

Here is one of this cases.
The `ImageView` is declared in the XML in this way:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/third_item_image_view"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/third_item_image_view"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first_item_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/d0_half"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/second_item_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/d0_half"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Both `ImgeView` have the same problem.

Here is how I load the images:

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(image.getAverageColor()))
            .error(R.drawable.image_error)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(imageView);
```

Pretty straightforward.

I solved this problem using a `SimpleTarget` instead of the `ImageView`

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(image.getAverageColor()))
            .error(R.drawable.image_error)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(resource.getCurrent());
                }
            });
```

So exactly the same code except for how I assign the image to the `ImageView`.

My question is what is the difference? Why Glide is working correctly only in the second case?

Comment: It's because you use **.fitCenter()** in Glide and in your XML use **FitXY** it's a bit Conflict and sometimes this issue happen.